# All combinations with all possible lengths (recursion, backtracking)

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, backtracking

I have an input of type tuple. The tuple has an **n-length**.(e.g. (1,1,2)) I also have a list of **n-elements**. (e.g. [A, B, C, D]) I need to get all possible combinations of elements grouped by the tuple. (w/o creating duplicates within each sublist. Within each sublist the order does not matter ) -->

```
[[[A],[BC],[D]]
 [[A],[BD],[C]]
       .
       .
       .
 [[B],[A],[CD]]
 [[B],[CD],[A]]
      .
      .
      . 
 [[C],[B],[DA]]]
```

I believe there should be no more than 12 solutions for the example above. (takes into account that there are no duplicates and each element is used.) --> this would be a prerequisite.

Due to performance constraints, I cannot create all possibilities and then filter out the invalid ones.

```
`                           [ ]
                             |
  A------------ B-----------------  C ------------------D 
  |
  |
  --------- -------------
  |         |           |
  B         C           C
  C         D           D
  |         |           |
  D         B           B`
```

I have tried the following, however I just cannot come up with a solution myself.

```
def distribution (tuple_,tuple_position, base_case, solution, all_solutions, already_chosen):
    print('----------Got Called--------------')
    tuple_length = len(tuple_)
    length_of_set = tuple_[tuple_position]
    print(f'Tuple length {length_of_set} at position {tuple_position}')
    
    base_case = powersetx((i for i in base_case), length_of_set)
    print(f'#1 Base case is {base_case} the length of the base case is {len(base_case)}')
    
    for i in base_case:
        solution.append(i)
        print (f'The solution is {solution}. The length of the solution is currently {len(solution)}')
        
        base_case = powersetx_remove(base_case, [i]) #--> This list now contains only e.g. (B), (C), (D)
        print(f'#2 Base case is {base_case}')

        if len(solution) < tuple_length:
            print('Ran into else. Will go deeper.')
            tuple_position +=1
            distribution(tuple_, tuple_position, base_case, solution, all_solutions)

            #solution = []
            #tuple_position = 0
            #all_solutions.append(solution)
            #print(f'The complete solution is {all_solutions}') 
            
        
        print('Ran into else. Will go deeper.')
        tuple_position +=1
        distribution(tuple_, tuple_position, base_case, solution,all_solutions)


    print('exicted for loop')
    all_solutions.append(solution)
    print(f'All solutions are currently {all_solutions}. The length is {len(all_solutions)}.')
    solution = []
    return print('----------exited function----------'), 

distribution ((1,1,2),0,['A','B','C','D'], [],[]) `
```

Comment: Does order matter? Do you distinguish `[[B],[A],[CD]]` from `[[A],[B],[CD]]`? What about from `[[CD],[A][B]]`, etc.? Is `[AB]` the same as `{BA]`? If so, I don't see where you got the number 12 in your question.

Comment: The order within the innermost lists does not matter. However, I would consider your example "[[B],[A],[CD]] from [[A],[B],[CD]]" as two different outcomes.

Comment: Where does the number 12 come from? 4 choose 2 = 6 ways to pick the 2 items to be grouped together. This determines the 2 singletons, but then since order of the overall list matters, the pair and the 2 singletons can be put in 3! = 6 possible orders. This leads to 6x6 = 36 solutions.

Comment: The 12 apply for this specific tuple. For all combinations in (1,1,2) (1,2,1) and (2,1,1) there would be 12 times 3 = 36. Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not run as shown.  There are several positional parameters to you function def, and you never specify the `already_chosen` parameter.  Either remove it, or specify it.

Also, to go deeper that that, it would be helpful to see your definition of `powersetx`.

Comment: I am sorry. Powerset x is basically combinations from itertools with the adjustment that instead of a generator a list is returned. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some codes that may not be your final solution, but may give you some ideas.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_list(n):
    m = n + 1
    while m < length:
        print(a[n] + a[m], end=' ')
        i = 0
        while i < length:
            if i != n and i != m:
                print(a[i], end=' ')
            i += 1
        print("")
        m += 1
       
a = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
length = len(a)
k = 0
while k < length - 1:
   get_list(k)
   k += 1
```

It will produce the following output.

```
AB C D 
AC B D 
AD B C 
BC A D 
BD A C 
CD A B
```